# General solution of Cauchy -Euler equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $x^2y''+\frac{5y}{4}=0, \ x>0.$ The general solution is: $c_1x^{1/2}\text{cos}(\text{ln}x)+c_2x^{1/2}\text{sin}(\text{ln}x), \ x>0$

Could anyone advise me how to show $y=x^{1/2}\text{sin}(\text{ln}\frac{x}{\alpha})$ also satisfies the differential equation, where $x>0, \ \alpha>1 \ ?$

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ln(x/a)=ln(x)-ln(a);
If you will expand Yp and take sin(ln(a)) as c1 and cos(ln(a)) as c2 it becomes similar to the general solution. You can't get a particular solution from a homogeneous equation without any initial values and an input function as disturbance to the system.